# mshapiro.test 'Error in solve.default(R %*% t(R), tol = 1e-18) : Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[7,7] = 0'

Tags: r, lapack, manova

I am trying to conduct a multivariate normality test using the *mvnormtest* package on my data with two between-subjects variables, one within-subjects, and three dependent variables (binary categorical). My data looks like this (~5,600 rows with no missing data):

```
Cluster Group   Trial   Measure Measure2    Measure
    1   4   1   1   1   0
    1   4   1   0   0   0
    1   4   1   1   1   0
    1   4   1   1   1   0
    1   4   1   1   1   1
    1   4   1   1   1   1
    1   4   1   1   1   0
    1   4   1   1   1   0
```

Here is my setup:

```
data.df <- read.csv(
"data.csv", 
  header=TRUE, sep=","
  )

attach(data.df)
names(data.df)
```

I attempted the following *mshapiro.test()*

```
#multivariate normality
dataMat <- data.matrix(data.df)
mshap <- mshapiro.test(dataMat)
```

I received the following error:

```
Error in solve.default(R %*% t(R), tol = 1e-18): 
Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[7,7] = 0.
```

I checked on a forum from my stats class a year ago, and found that someone was able to work it by dividing the data into groups.

```
LowCluster <- t(dataMat[c(1:1877),1:6])
MedCluster <- t(dataMat[c(1878:3166),1:6])
HigCluster <- t(dataMat[c(3167:5364),1:6])
mshaplow <- mshapiro.test(LowCluster)
mshapmed <- mshapiro.test(MedCluster)
mshaphigh <- mshapiro.test(HigCluster)
```

I got the same error.

```
Error in solve.default(R %*% t(R), tol = 1e-18) : 
Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[7,7] = 0
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple issues. First, the `mshapiro.test` function requires the data to be in row format, so you need to use `t()` to transpose your data.

But it will still fail due to singular matrix because you have columns that are exactly linear combinations of each other. For example, `Group` is equal to `4*Cluster`, and `Measure` is the same as `Measure2`. Check out [this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70899/what-correlation-makes-a-matrix-singular-and-what-are-implications-of-singularit) on singular matrices for more info.

Assuming you only want to test normality on the `Measure` variables, here is a sample of code that will work to illustrate the singular matrix issue:

```
df2 <- data.df[,c(4, 5, 6)]
df2[8,1] = 0 # changing this value makes it so no column is a linear combo of any other column
mshapiro.test(t(df2))
```

But are all of your `Measure` values 0 or 1? If so, why would you test for normality?